# Como manter indentação e quebras de linha ao salvar um arquivo texto via javascript

Tags: javascript

consegui achar um script que salva um arquivo texto (client-side). 
link de acesso: http://thiscouldbebetter.neocities.org/texteditor.html

A dúvida: digamos que eu "printe" isso na caixa de texto e mande salvar, como salvar o arquivo exatamente identado assim:

**gostaria de imprimir no arquivo assim, com as linhas "puladas"**

```
    <p class="algo">algumacoisa
    <span class="label" id="label1"><img src="img/img1.png" /></span>
    <span class="sucesso" id="sucesso1"><img src="img/img2.png" /></span></p>
    <textarea  name="justresp1" ></textarea>
```

**quando o arquivo é gerado, ele acaba sendo salvo em uma única linha**

```
    <p class="algo">algumacoisa <span class="label" id="label1"><img src="img/img1.png" /></span>   <span class="sucesso" id="sucesso1"><img src="img/img2.png" /></span></p>       <textarea  name="justresp1" ></textarea>
```

vocês tem alguma dica?

Comment: Apenas uma dica, se você clicar com o botão direito nessa página e em Inspecionar Elemento, no final vai ter todo o código javascript do site, incluindo a função que você quer :)

Comment: eu já tenho o código em mãos, está salvando certinho =). o problema é no arquivo gerado, ele não salva as linhas "puladas", será que há alguma dica para implementar isso?

Comment: Nos meus testes, as quebras de linha são salvas normalmente. Você está usando um input ou textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As quebras de linha estão no ficheiro gerado, mas isso não quer dizer que o programa que usas para ler o ficheiro entenda o que lá está.

Um ficheiro pode ser guardado com três tipos de caracteres de controle que representam a terminação de uma linha num documento texto:

- `CR`

  Comum nos sistemas operativos Mac, vem de **C**arriage  **R**eturn.
  Codificação: 0x0D (13 decimal)
- `LF`

  Comum nos sistemas operativos Unix, vem de **L**ine **F**eed.
  Codificação: 0x0A (10 decimal)
- `CR/LF`

  Comum nos sistemas operativos Windows.

Qualquer um dos terminadores de linhas em cima indicados é perfeitamente válido, mas nem todos os programas os entendem, dando origem a que o conteúdo do ficheiro apareça numa só linha.

## Solução

A solução passa por fazer uso do terminador de linha que nos convém, onde para o efeito, após lermos o texto a guardar, manipulamos o mesmo para uniformizar os resultados.

Dado que os navegadores utilizam diferentes terminadores de linha uns dos outros: `\r` ou `\n` ou `\r\n` respetivamente, o mais certo parece ser a utilização do terminador de linha adequado para o sistema operativo do utilizador.

Assim sendo, fica um exemplo em baixo para testarmos e realizar um simples teste de  digitar duas ou mais linhas de texto e clicar num botão.

**O que vai acontecer é:**

- Ler o valor da `textarea`;
- Separar o texto para uma matriz onde cada entrada é uma linha lida, recorrendo a uma expressão regular que procurar pelos 3 possíveis terminadores de linha;
- Voltar a juntar o texto com o terminador de linha adequado para o sistema operativo detetado:

  Fazemos uso das informações fornecidas pela propriedade [`navigator.appVersion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appVersion) e tentamos localizar um indicador do sistema operativo para devolver o terminador de linha correspondente:

  ```
  function qualOS() {
    var x = "\r\n";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) x = '\r\n';
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) x = '\r';
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11") != -1) x = '\n';
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux") != -1) x = '\n';
    return x;
  }
  ```
- Disparar um alerta para vermos o texto.

## Exemplo

```js
function qualOS() {
  var x = "\r\n";
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) x = '\r\n';
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) x = '\r';
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11") != -1) x = '\n';
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux") != -1) x = '\n';
  return x;
}

function testar() {

  var texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;

  var linhas = texto.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);

  var textoFinal = linhas.join(qualOS());

  alert(textoFinal);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="texto"></textarea>
<p>
  <button onclick="testar()">testar</button>
</p>
```

Este código, no teu caso, será para ser aplicado entre a leitura do valor da `textarea` e o gerar do `blob`:

```
function saveTextAsFile() {

  var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;

  // aqui, fazer aqui a verificação e conversão do terminado de linha

  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com um [comentário do próprio autor](https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/#comment-1542) do script que você linkou:

**Tradução**:

> As quebras de linha ainda estão lá, mas estão formatadas em estilo
>   Unix, e não em estilo Windows. O Unix usa apenas o caractere
>   *linefeed* para codificar quebras de linha, que normalmente aparece como `\n`. O Windows, por outro lado, *carriage return* e *linefeed*
>   para codificar quebras de linhas, que são representados como `\r\n`.
>   Então, para salvar no estilo Windows, você provavelmente vai precisar
>   de algo como:
>
> ```
> textToWrite = textToWrite.replace(“\n”, “\r\n”);
> ```
>
> Alternativamente, você pode abrir os arquivos salvos em um programa
>   que entende o estilo Unix, como Notepad++.

**Original**:

> The line breaks are still there, but they’re Unix-formatted rather
>   than Windows-formatted. Unix uses just the “linefeed” control
>   character to encode line breaks, which is commonly encoded as `\n`.
>   Windows, on the other hand, uses a carriage return AND a line feed to
>   encode line breaks, which is represented like this: `\r\n`. So in
>   order to save the file with Windows-style line breaks, you’ll need to
>   add something like:
>
> ```
> textToWrite = textToWrite.replace(“\n”, “\r\n”);
> ```
>
> Alternately, you could open the saved text file with a program that
>   understands Linux-style line breaks, like Notepad++.